# How do I install kwin?

Tags: kde, kwin

I have installed KDE by command sudo apt-get install kde-window-manager , but i am getting plasma, ubuntu, ubuntu 2d, metacity, failsafe but not Kwin what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `kde-window-manager` is `kwin`

Answer (score 1):

As @warwaruk said, you already have KWin. "Plasma" is the name of the desktop environment that uses KWin, so you should select Plasma when you log in.

You said "I have installed KDE by command sudo apt-get install kde-window-manager". If you want the full KDE environment, you should install *kubuntu-desktop* or at least *kde-workspace*, to be sure you're not missing any parts.